# Adding a search form inside a div

Tags: php, html, genesis-theme-framework

I wanted to add a search form inside a div using the code bellow:

`printf( '<div class="entry"><p>%s</p>%s</div>', apply_filters( 'genesis_noposts_text', __( 'Try again below.', 'genesis' ) ), get_search_form() );`

But every time I add the `get_search_form()` it's generated before the div, like the following:

```
<form></form>
<div class="entry"></div>
```

The workaround I found was to split the code, but I wanted to know if there is a better solution that works properly.

```
remove_action( 'genesis_loop_else', 'genesis_do_noposts' );
add_action( 'genesis_loop_else', 'mytheme_do_noposts' );
function mytheme_do_noposts() {

    printf( '<div class="entry"><p>%s</p>', apply_filters( 'genesis_noposts_text', __( 'Try again below.', 'genesis' ) ) );

    printf( '%s</div>', get_search_form() );

}
```

---

[get_search_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `get_search_form()` echos so it will always show up before returns. Use:

```
get_search_form( false )
```

Comment: My god, it really worked. I've been trying get_search_form( 'false' ) without success because I because I saw it in a post. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use `get_search_form( false )`.

`get_search_form()` will output the `search form`. Since you are trying to use the result in a string context, you need the function to return the `html` in form of a string, which you are passing through `printf`.

The only parameter for `get_search_form` controls that behavior. By default it prints, but if you pass `false`, it will return the string that you need.